# Having trouble with infinite while loop and label update (Python AppJar)

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface

I'm making a script that update my "Result" **EmptyLabel** with the most up-to-date value of the message as long as the **GO** variable is **FALSE**.

My problem is that appJar windows gets stuck ("Not Responding") because it includes while loop. I've tried a lot of ways to solve the problem, but it still gets hung up on the same issue. There must be a way for the while loop to go on in the background and still update the GUI (Within the while loop).

Below you can find my code:

```
from appjar import gui

def press(button):
    if button == "PLAY":
        app.disableButton("PLAY")
        Main(A, B, C)
    else:
        app.errorBox("Error", "Error")

def Main(A, B, C):
    GO = False

    while not GO:
        message = 'From: {0}\nTo: {1}.'.format(A, B)

        if int(num) <= C:
            GO = True
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            app.setLabel("Result", message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = gui()

    app = gui("Login Window", "420x300")

    app.addEmptyLabel("Result", 3, 0, 4)
    app.setLabelRelief("Result", app.GROOVE)
    app.setLabelAlign("Result", app.NW)
    app.setLabelHeight("Result", 8)

    app.addButtons(["PLAY", "Reset", "Cancel"], press, 4, 0, 4)

    app.go()
```

Python Version: 2.7.3
appJar GUI Version: 0.61
[image]
Can you assist, please ?

Comment: How far does it get? Is it possible to see the console and see what is causing the break?

Comment: As soon as I press the PLAY button the screen and the button gets stuck.

Comment: Where/how does `num` get set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a `while` loop will cause the GUI's event loop to hang. The GUI won't become responsive again, until the while loop ends.

The code you've provided doesn't work, so I can;t test it out.

But have a look here: http://appjar.info/pythonEvents/#repeating-events for some advice on using appJar to make things repeat.